# iterating Javascript array and delete based on condition

Tags: javascript

I want to iterate through an array of words, look up the definition and delete the word if no definition is found.

my code looks as follows;

```
var words = ["word1", "word2", "word3",]

function Meaning(words){
           const getMeaning = async () => {
  const response = await fetch(`https://api.dictionaryapi.dev/api/v2/entries/en/${words}`)
  const myJson = await response.json()

            for(i = 0; i < words.length; ++i) {
                if(!response[i]){
                    myJson.splice(i,1)
                    console.log(myJson)
                }
            }}
```

This is not really doing anything atm. Where am I going wrong?

edit to add context

tried like this as well;

```
for(i = 0; i < words.length; ++i)
fetch(`https://api.dictionaryapi.dev/api/v2/entries/en/${words[i]}`).then((response) => {
  if (response === 404) {
    let response = words
    words[i].splice(i,1)
    console.log(response)
  }
  throw new Error('Something went wrong');
})
.then((responseJson) => {
    let response = words
    response[i].splice(i,1)

})
.catch((error) => {
  console.log(error)
});
```

I can print out the 404 error when it finds no definition, but I can't remove it from the words array

Comment: thank you very much Ali for taking time to answer, sadly still the same.

Comment: @kip, You need to make few modifications. Check this example https://codepen.io/Maniraj_Murugan/pen/qBKPLvV . But your problem is not clear yet, could you elaborate what you are trying to achive?

Comment: Thanks Maniraj for taking time to answer. Basically I want to iterate through the list of words, fetch the meaning, and if there is no meaning to the word, I want to delete it from the list.

Comment: @AliBahrami That is incorrect. `splice` mutates the array, there's no need to assign it back

Comment: You are looping through the `words` array , checking `!response[i]` in the if condition and removing that `i` index from `myJson`. What are you trying to do? What is the expected output?

Comment: thanks Adiga, I want to remove it from the words array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After quick look at the API, and it appears to handle only single words, so the caller needs to make the requests one at a time. Here's how to do it...

```js
const baseUrl = 'https://api.dictionaryapi.dev/api/v2/entries/en/';

// one word lookup. resolve to an array of definitions
async function lookupWord(word) {
  const res = await fetch(baseUrl + word);
  return res.json();
}

// resolve to a bool, true if the word is in the corpus
async function spellCheck(word) {
  const defArray = await lookupWord(word);
  return Array.isArray(defArray) && defArray.length > 0;
}

// create a spellCheck promise for every word and resolve with the results
// note, this mutates the array and resolves to undefined
async function spellCheckWords(array) {
  const checks = await Promise.all(array.map(spellCheck));
  for (let i=array.length-1; i>=0; i--) {
    if (!checks[i]) array.splice(i,1);
  }
}


// test it (a little)
let array = ['hello', 'whereforeartthou', 'coffee'];
spellCheckWords(array).then(() => {
  console.log(array)
})
```

Comment: thank you dank for taking time to answer me. The code doesn't seem remove the word from the original array.

Comment: Hi @kip - it's straight-forward to mutate the input instead of filtering. edited to demonstrate. run the test and pls notice that the original input array is logged.

Answer (score 0):

try this code, you need to check every single element of array from response

```js
var words = ["word1", "word2", "word3"];

function Meaning(words) {
    const getMeaning = async () => {
        const response = await fetch(`https://api.dictionaryapi.dev/api/v2/entries/en/${words}`)
        const myJson = await response.json()
        let result = [];
        myJson.forEach(element => {
            if(words.includes(element)) {
                result.push(element)
            }
        });

        return result;
    }
    return getMeaning();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but I think you should iterate throw words and not myJson.

Why not just return `words.filter(word => myJson.includes(word))` instead of doing the forEach loop

Comment: thanks Build for Dev. sadly same issue.